# Need to create a row of 10 numbers while having multiples of 6

Tags: java

This is what i have so far. I have the multiples of 6 part working but when i try stuff to get 10 numbers per line it does not seem to work.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("*****Results*****");
    int multipleOf6 = 6;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i+=6){
          System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: What is the reason for `multipleOf6`? You are not using it.

Comment: `System.out.print(i); if(i%10 == 0){system.out.println();}` Change the inside of your loop to that. Send me a comment (using @Knells at the start of your comment) if you want it explained and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Knells That doesn't work because the for loop doesn't use `i++`. It uses `i+=6`.

Comment: @Gendarme Oh shoot, I need a coffee or something. Should be i%60.

Comment: @dan d - check my response as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`println()` starts a new line after it has printed, which you only want after every 10th number. To print without starting a new line, use `print()`.

Here is a simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++) { //notice i++ instead of i+=6
        if(i % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println(); //this happens every 10th iteration
        }
        System.out.print(i*6 + " "); //multiple of 6
    }
}
```

`System.out.println()` is used alone to just start a new line. It doesn't actually print any text.

Comment: You're going to have an extra new line at the beginning because 0%10 == 0.

Comment: @DavidDennis Now that you said that, what is the point of starting at 0 anyway? `0*6` is pretty useless. I'll edit it.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. I understand now what i did wrong. i should use this website more often.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` terminates a "row", so you shouldn't be calling `System.out.println` in every cycle of your `for` loop.

**Hint:** use `System.out.print(i)` and only call `System.out.println()` every 10 numbers using another `int` as counter.

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8 is cool!

Switch to Java 8!

```
    int[] numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).filter(i -> i % 60 == 0).toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("*****Results*****");
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 6) {
        count++;
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        if(count > 10){
            System.out.println(" ");
            count = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i understand that he needs 10 number per line in each line. sorry

Comment: My bad. I didn't see that you had written `count = 1;`.